# Serialize and deserialize in Android

Tags: android, xml, serialization

I'm developing a Restful web services in Java using JERSEY technology. I have currently developed all the server side.

The client side of this project would be an Android application. I have done the communication between server and client (I can send information through Android and receive it in the web service). The problem is that I'm having problems with the serialization and deserialization problems in the client side.

The web service side using JERSEY does it automatically, but I didn't find any client in Android to serialize and deserialze in XML. Any suggestion?

Do I have to do it manually (handling the xml and deserializing it with whiles, and so..)?

Comment: No idea about automation, but still you can encode/decode content to base32 String and serialize/deserialize it while communicating.